# nvm not found with new setup

Tags: node.js, terminal, nvm

I can't seem to figure out why nvm isn't being found.

I'm sure I am missing something so obvious here.

Nvm is install, npm install, and node.

And it's saying nvm command not found. I've tried setting up the environment twice now with no luck.

Does nvm version matter?

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: It's definitely a path issue. There's not enough information in your question to determine *which* path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your terminal uses zsh but npm run uses sh, in your OS set zsh as default shell or set zsh as script shell in npm like this:
`npm config set script-shell "/bin/zsh"`